# Class does not override abstract method onPositiveClick(int)

Tags: java, android

What's wrong with my code? I extending my class to `fragment` and implements `AlertDialogRadio.AlertPositiveListener from another class.` But I get the error and I have no idea on how to solve it.

**Claims.java**

```
public class Claims extends Fragment implement AlertPositiveListener  {
    Intent intent;
    int position=0;

    @Override 
    public void onPositiveClick(int position){
    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View claims= inflater.inflate(R.layout.claims, container, false);
        View.OnClickListener listener =new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                FragmentManager manager =getFragmentManager();
                AlertDialogRadio alert = new AlertDialogRadio();
                /** Creating a bundle object to store the selected item's index */
                Bundle b  = new Bundle();

                /** Storing the selected item's index in the bundle object */
                b.putInt("position", position);

                /** Setting the bundle object to the dialog fragment object */
                alert.setArguments(b);

                /** Creating the dialog fragment object, which will in turn open the alert dialog window */
                alert.show(manager, "alert_dialog_radio");
            }
        };
        Button button1=(Button)claims.findViewById(R.id.button10);
        Button button=(Button)claims.findViewById(R.id.button8);
        button1.setOnClickListener(listener);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), CameraMain.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return claims;
    }
}
```

**AlertDialogRadio.java**

```
public class AlertDialogRadio extends DialogFragment {
    /** Declaring the interface, to invoke a callback function in the implementing activity class */
    AlertPositiveListener alertPositiveListener;

    /** An interface to be implemented in the hosting activity for "OK" button click listener */
   public interface AlertPositiveListener {

        public void onPositiveClick(int position);
    }

    /** This is a callback method executed when this fragment is attached to an activity.
     *  This function ensures that, the hosting activity implements the interface AlertPositiveListener
     * */
    public void onAttach(android.app.Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try{
            alertPositiveListener = (AlertPositiveListener) activity;
        }catch(ClassCastException e){
            // The hosting activity does not implemented the interface AlertPositiveListener
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement AlertPositiveListener");
        }
    }

    /** This is the OK button listener for the alert dialog,
     *  which in turn invokes the method onPositiveClick(position)
     *  of the hosting activity which is supposed to implement it
     */
    OnClickListener positiveListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            AlertDialog alert = (AlertDialog)dialog;
            int position = alert.getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();
            alertPositiveListener.onPositiveClick(position);
        }
    };

    public void setListener(AlertPositiveListener alertPositiveListener){
        this.alertPositiveListener=alertPositiveListener;
    }


    /** This is a callback method which will be executed
     *  on creating this fragment
     */
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        /** Getting the arguments passed to this fragment */
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        int position = bundle.getInt("position");

        /** Creating a builder for the alert dialog window */
        AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        /** Setting a title for the window */
        b.setTitle("Choose your version");

        /** Setting items to the alert dialog */
        b.setSingleChoiceItems(Android.code, position, null);

        /** Setting a positive button and its listener */
        b.setPositiveButton("OK",positiveListener);

        /** Setting a positive button and its listener */
        b.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);

        /** Creating the alert dialog window using the builder class */
        AlertDialog d = b.create();

        /** Return the alert dialog window */
        return d;
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
Error:(17, 8) error: Claims is not abstract and does not override abstract method onPositiveClick(int) in AlertPositiveListener
```

How can I solve this ? Thanks

After change from `implement` to `implements`

**Error** (The latest)

```
10-25 02:21:10.072  10543-10543/com.example.project.project E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project.project, PID: 10543
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.project.project.MainActivity@422b7768 must implement AlertPositiveListener
            at com.example.project.project.AlertDialogRadio.onAttach(AlertDialogRadio.java:32)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:849)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
```

Comment: hmm dude why not overriding `onPositiveClick` method in `Claims` class? just `@Override public void onPositiveClick(int position){}` in `Claims` class

Comment: I don't have onPositiveClick method in Claims class

Comment: Yes you don't have, and that is the problem. You need to create that method (override).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the method in your claims class. Whenever you implement an Interface in your class you must override its methods.

Comment: I can't see the method override in the claims class.

Comment: Can you see if you are getting the same error or do you have any other error in this class. Also try to compile your source once again.

Comment: should be implements not implement :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93256/discussion-between-vivek-singh-and-hoo).

Comment: So the issue was related to the Implementation of the MainActivity class. It had to implement the AlertPositiveListener and it worked